# How to get usefull data with the API from data.fao.org?

Tags: xml, json, web-services, api

I need help to understand the use of the API from http://data.fao.org.

That site offers a query builder [http://api.data.fao.org/1.0/query-api-builder.html][1].
But I'm not able to select something like:

```
SELECT all countries that have a faostat_id between 1 to 12 
AND SELECT all cattles from this countries in the years 2010 - 2011.
```

It would be much easier if there is a list to look for available properties and elements.
But I can't find this.

The best result I've got so far is this here:

```
http://data.fao.org/developers/api/v1/en/resources/faostat/live-prod/facts.xml?
filter=cnt.iso3 eq AFG 
and item.label eq Cattle    
and year eq 2008 & 
fields=year,
cnt.iso3 as country,
item.label,
m5111 as Stocks
```

And that is the URL build from the Query Builder:

http://data.fao.org/developers/api/v1/en/resources/faostat/live-prod/facts.xml?filter=cnt.iso3%20eq%20AFG%20and%20item.label%20eq%20Cattle%20and%20year%20eq%202010&fields=year%2C%20cnt.iso3%20as%20Country%2C%20item.label%2C%20m5111%20as%20Stocks

Comment: APIs are completely new to me, but it seems like you can do what you want to here with SDMX. See the example here: http://data.fao.org/sdmx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is using an API always preferable to scraping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101763/is-using-an-api-always-preferable-to-scraping)

Comment: Note: There appears to be a newer API from FAOSTAT here: http://faostat.github.io/faostat-api/